# Repeater: redirect to another page when if label equal value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

hello i want to redirect to another page  if label in repeater value equals C# and the button is clicked.

here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
    String name;
    name = (item.FindControl("lblname") as Label).Text;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (name=="Csharp") { Response.Redirect("Csharp.aspx"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: And you did not mention what went wrong.

Comment: it doesnt redirect to the desired page, it actually wont redirect at all.

Comment: Is your control in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no, it is in a a Repeater

Comment: Please share the source code of both aspx and aspx.cs so we can help.